# Structured data on dynamic pages

Tags: seo, structured-data

If we have a URL like example.org/page that has a sidebar that changes depending on what store the user is viewing, does it make sense to add structured data to this sidebar?

My thought is if the URL is going to stay the same but the structured data change than it doesn't really make sense to have it there. We wouldn't want a search engine to attach data to a URL that could have different structured data that changes. Like it wouldn't make sense if Google Indexed it for "Location A", but a user searching for "Location B" sees "Location A's" data would it? Maybe I am overthinking this? Wouldn't it make more sense to keep structured data on pages with unique URLs: (IE example.org/location_a)?

What is the proper manner to handle structured data in this circumstance?